# magento2 swatch attributes

Tags: magento-2.1, configurable-swatches

How to show swatch images on the info tab in the product page?
by default, magento2 shows the value of swatches in the info tab on the product page and shows swatch images on top of product for configurable products.
but I want to show swatch image instead of the value in more info tab.
EX. I have an attribute name test and has 3 options(toy-with image 1, girl-with image2, boy- with image 3) I want to show image 1 on the product more info tab on product page instead of show toy. on Magento 2.1. thanks 
Use swatches icon instead of text on any page

Comment: Any good news guys?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add your base code to attributes.phtml also you can use label or value to change to.

Comment: Your welcome @MGPM